# Fetch returns unathorized and undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch, http-status-code-401, unauthorized, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to access to an API using fetch however the error I receive in console:

```
XHR GET https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?street=buenos%20aires&city=barcelona&country=espa%C3%B1a&lang=es&limit=1&format=json&apiKey=hereIputmyrealkey 
Estado 401 Unauthorized 
Versión HTTP/2 
Transferido1,52 KB (tamaño 97 B) 
Política de referenciastrict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

The fetch looks like this:

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
credentials: "include"
};

let response = await fetch("https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?street=buenos aires&city=barcelona&country=españa&lang=es&limit=1&format=json&apiKey=${MYKEY}");
```

When I add:

```
.then(error => console.log(error)
```

It return response undefined.

I'm working on cakephp, the url for the fetch works and outside of cakephp the fetch works too. Do I need to add something to the fetch?

(The key in my code is my actual key and the url gives a response in json format).

I tried adding:

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
credentials: "include"
};
```

and

```
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET', 
  mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
};
```

but it gives the same error...

Comment: use `\`` not `"` if you want to use `${MYKEY}` - since the request, as you've written it is *literally* with `apiKey=${MYKEY}` rather than your *actual* key

Comment: I just used that to not publish my key in the code I put the real key

Comment: right ... I would suggest, so others don't get confused that you don't use template literal syntax in the question :p

Comment: 401 would suggest that the key you are using is not valid

Comment: However when I copy the url with the key in browser it works, and in a independent file (outside cakephp) it works too ...

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302262/fetch-gives-cross-origin-error-in-cakephp), edit the existing question instead.

Comment: https://apidocs.geoapify.com/docs/geocoding/forward-geocoding/#quick-start says you can set up CORS from their pages, that's where you have to add localhost or whatever else where your development code is hosted. As CORS only applies when a request is initiated by a webpage, that's why it works from the JS console, and in non-browser contexts in general.

Comment: @tevemadar - that explains that mystery - it's documented

Comment: @tevemadar When I said in independent file I mean in a individual file in a browser context. And in the documentation url I only found  "Optionally, you can protect the API key by listing allowed IP addresses, HTTP referrers, origins, and CORS." , but that is for protection not to stop the error... I'm working in localhost

Comment: The `credentials: "include"` looks suspicious, it's not used anywhere on that documentation page, and it may encourage the browser to send something what results in the 401 - do you have that in the working page too? Personally I'd skip the entire options thing, as `method: 'GET'` is the default anyway.

Comment: @tevemadar Even without the options it gives the error 401

Comment: I think is something related to XHR and CORS but I just can't find what

Comment: As there's a working sample too, a thing you can try is comparing the actual requests. Open 2 windows/tabs, open the developer tools and go to the network view in both, then open the two pages. In order to have "clean", "full" requests you may want to disable the cache, usually it's a checkbox also in the network view. Then it's all about eyeballing, usually you click on the first column with the URL to open the details, so see the outgoing and incoming headers, which may make the difference.

Comment: @tevemadar the diference I see is that the origin of the one that doesn't work has a referer and in the response it allows referers

Comment: You may have a HTML-level referrer setting in the non-working page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#integration_with_html . You can probably keep it if it's needed, but then go back to having an options object, and supply a [`referrerPolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#referrerpolicy), I'd guess `"no-referrer"` is the one supressing the header.

Comment: You're explicitly excluding cross-domain requests by setting `mode: 'no-cors'`. Also, please re-read tevemadar's first comment, you've to set the CORS origins on your setting page at geoapify.com, they can't allow your origin(s) without you specifying those origins first (I'm not sure if this will work with localhost at all, though, as it's not considered as a real web server).

Answer (score 0):

Use back ticks when adding ${variable}

```
let response = await fetch(`https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/search?street=buenos aires&city=barcelona&country=españa&lang=es&limit=1&format=json&apiKey=${MYKEY}`);
```

Comment: read the comments and the edited question :p

Comment: Ah, well posting an API access key in the front end code would be considered bad practice, so it would make sense to have it somewhere in an .env file

Comment: yeah, not sure how that's related to the question or answer, but I do agree, if this is on the front end (fetch suggests it is even though nodejs now has fetch), putting the key there would be unwise, and a `.env` file won't help that